# Getting TypeError from class representing a geometric sphere,

Tags: python, class

I am working on a project in python, I can not figure out why I am getting an error on the project.

The project is as follows.

1. Write a class to represent the geometric sphere. Your class should implement the following methods:

   - `__init__(self, radius)` Creates a sphere having the giving radius.
   - `getRadius(self)` Returns the radius of this sphere
   - `surfaceArea(self)` Returns the surface area of the sphere. 
     Formula for area is Surface Area = 4πr2
   - `volume(self)` Returns the volume of the sphere. Formula for volume is
2. Write a `main()` method that prompts the user for the radius of the sphere and tells the user what the surface area and volume is for the given radius.

My current code is as follows.

```
import math
class Spheres:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.area = 0
        self.volumeResult = 0

    def getRadius(self):
        return self.radius

    def surfaceArea(self):
        r = self.radius
        self.area = 4 * math.pi * (r * r)
        return self.area

    def volume(self):
        r = self.radius
        self.volumeResult = (4/3) * math.pi * (r * r * r)
        return self.volumeResult

def main():
    r = input("enter radius of circle:")
    r = int(r)
    radius = Spheres(r)
    v = radius.volume()
    a = radius.surfaceArea()

    print ("volume of circle :" , v () )
    print ("Surface Area of circle:" , a () )

main()
```

When I run the code it looks like this

```
enter radius of circle:5   #### i enter 5 here to test it
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\python bonus project\AustinBaker Python
bonus.py", line 30, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\python bonus project\AustinBaker Python
bonus.py", line 27, in main
print ("volume of circle :" , v () )
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
>>>
```

I don't understand why the code is not working at all.

Comment: `print ("volume of circle :" , v )`. You can't call a `float`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
print ("volume of circle :" , v () )
print ("Surface Area of circle:" , a () )
```

You are attempting to call `v` and `a` but those variables aren't callable they are `float`s.

```
In [1]: v = 12.4

In [2]: callable(v)
Out[2]: False

In [3]: type(v)
Out[3]: float
```

Just `print("volume of circle :" , v)` without the `()`.

For future reference, the traceback is your friend:

```
File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\python bonus project\AustinBaker Python
bonus.py", line 27, in main  <--- ## the line number in your program where it all went wrong
print ("volume of circle :" , v () )  <-- ## the line of code that crapped out
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable  <-- ## why it crapped out
```

Translation:

1. in line 27 in your main function
2. you attempted to call a variable of type `float`

So if `v = 12.4`, you tried to call it like a function:
   `print ("volume of circle :" , v () ) # ==> 12.4()`

That's your error...

Some suggestions:

```
class Sphere:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self._radius = radius
        self._area = None
        self._volume = None  
    @property
    def area(self):
        if self._area is None:
            r = self.radius         
            self._area = 4 * math.pi * (r * r)            
        return self._area
    @property
    def volume(self):
        if self._volume is None:
            r = self.radius         
            self._volume = (4/3) * math.pi * (r * r * r) 
        return self._volume
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius
    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        self._radius = radius
        self._area = None
        self._volume = None
```

So this way:

```
In [1]: s = Sphere(2)

In [2]: s.area
Out[2]: 50.26548245743669

In [3]: s.volume
Out[3]: 33.510321638291124

In [4]: s.radius = 3

In [5]: s.volume
Out[5]: 113.09733552923254

In [6]: s.area
Out[6]: 113.09733552923255
```